# How to check ErrorCode for REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG?

Tags: c#, com, exception, comexception

```
try
{
    // call to Com Method
}
catch (COMException e)
{
    if (e.ErrorCode == 0x80040154) // REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG.
    {
       // handle this error.
    }
}
```

I would like to check if com exception is thrown due to `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` then handle it. I tried with the code above but it gives warning:

```
Comparison to integral constant is useless; the constant is outside the range of type 'int'
```

I believe this error is due to `0x80040154` is not in Int32 range.

Can you suggest any possible solution? or Is there any other way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing with its integer equivalent works fine:

```
if (e.ErrorCode == -2147287036) // REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG.
{
   // handle this error.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the *unchecked* keyword:

```
        catch (COMException ex) {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == unchecked((int)0x80040514)) {
                //...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by using some text that is displayed in Exception message/Error Message like follows

```
try
 {  
   // call to Com Method
 } 
catch (COMException e) 
{ 
    if (e.ToString().Contains("Your Error Text here")) // REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. 
    {   
     // handle this error.
    }
 }
```