# Defined constant to check ErrorCode for REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mono

I saw [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790203/how-to-check-errorcode-for-regdb-e-classnotreg), but it always scares me to hard-code these types of values (especially because I want my application to run on Windows and Mono). Is there a defined constant for REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG that I can just use in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a defined constant for `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` that I can just use in the code?

**Snarky answer:**

Yes, it looks like this:

```
public const int REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG = unchecked((int)0x80040154);
```

**Real answer:**

No, there is nothing public in the .NET Framework that defines that value for you. The fact that a `COMException` is being thrown in the first place is an indication that the particular error code (actually an `HRESULT` value returned by the underlying COM functions) is not one that the .NET Framework recognizes and automatically maps to a more specific and informative exception type. As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) indicates, `COMException` is really an all-purpose exception that includes the `ErrorCode` property specifically so that you can check the `HRESULT` returned by the callee and determine the underlying cause of the generic exception.

Those `HRESULT` values are actually defined in the Windows header files included with the Windows SDK. You would `#include` those headers when writing a Windows application in C or C++, but in the managed world of .NET, you need to define them yourself by copying the appropriate definitions into your source file.

The good news is it's extremely unlikely that this value will ever change, at least on Windows, given how important backwards compatibility is and how many applications would break. Values like this can be reasonably assumed to be constants. I still wouldn't hardcode them as a "magic number" just in case, though. By defining a public constant (as I did above), it it *did* change, you would only have to alter your code in one place and then recompile.

As far as Mono is concerned, if they need this value, they're going to ultimately have done the same thing as I described above. Somewhere in one of their source files for their version of the runtime are a bunch of declarations like `internal const int ...`.

Comment: It is `0x80040154` **not** `0x80040514`.